# PreUpdate Hooks in play framework, how to get the old value of the request?

Tags: java, ebean, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to use EBEAN preUpdate hooks. I've setup a test class in this way

```
public class MessageController extends BeanPersistAdapter {

@Override
public boolean isRegisterFor(Class<?> cls) {
    if (cls.equals(Message.class)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void postLoad(Object bean, Set<String> includedProperties) {
}

@Override
public boolean preUpdate(BeanPersistRequest<?> request) {
    Logger.info("Update Record!");
    // Message bean = request.getBean();
    Message newModel = (Message) request.getBean();
    Message oldModel = (Message) request.getOldValues();
    //      
    System.out.println("... OrderController > inserting: "+ newModel.title);
    System.out.println("... OrderController > replacing: "+ oldModel.title);
    return true;

}
```

The problem is that, newModel.title and oldModel.title returs the same values.
What I'm miss?

Comment: And you are changing `title` value? Do you have the full class name in ebean settings in `application.conf`? From here it seems alright

Comment: Of course :) for both ... should i've to declare a specific package or name-space?